# Upgrade from basic to standard azure load balancer with cli on Linux?

Tags: azure-cli

How does one upgrade from the basic load balancer to the standard one on Azure
without using the powershell script referred to in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/upgrade-basic-standard ?

I'd like to do it entirely with the azure cli.

Comment: Hello @Dan, Did the below answer helped? If so, please accept the answer so community can benefit from it. Do you have any further questions regarding the same.

Comment: Any more updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, to upgrade Azure Load Balancer from Basic to Standard, it seems it only supports PowerShell currently and you cannot change them into CLI.